# Water dripping inside furnace

Tags: water, furnace

We've got a Carrier Infinity, 2 stage, high efficiency furnace.

I noticed water on the floor just underneath the furnace, and can hear a metallic dripping sound. When I opened it up, I do see water dripping at the very back of the bottom of the furnace.

Is this something I can fix myself? Or do I need to call HVAC repair? And if so, what is (most likely) wrong and how much will it cost me?

I checked, its not the condensate tube that leads to the pump (which has given us issues in the past)

Comment: If "it's not *the* condensate" (one of the 3 lines, or the stupid little drain box thing itself), then you've a problem. "Water on the Floor - If moisture has buildup on the floor at the foundation of your furnace, then the most probable cause is a **cracked heat exchanger**. While leaking water is common in high-efficiency furnaces due to the condensation process, it’s rare in standard-efficiency ones." https://andersonair.com/8-symptoms-of-a-cracked-heat-exchanger/ - There's a *working* CO detector in the house, right?

Comment: Do you have a humidifier installed there at the furnace?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely causes are leak in the condensate or you have high humidity in the room and your house air is condensing on a cold portion causing the drips.  Both should be fixable with some level of DIY skills.